# Esconder e Mostrar todos os li decendentes de um ul - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho as seguintes listas:

```
<h4>Procedures</h4>
<ul>
  <li">Foo</li>
  <li">Foobar</li>
  <li">FooBarBazz</li>
</ul>

<h4>Packages</h4>
<ul>
  <li">Foo</li>
  <li">Foobar</li>
  <li">FooBarBazz</li>
</ul>
```

Tentei com esse JQuery, mas não deu certo...

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('h4').click(function(){
     this>li.toggle();
   });
});
</script>
```

Queria poder, assim que clicar em no H4 correspondente esconder e mostrar a lista como em um toggle, como devo proceder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cada `ul` é irmão (*sibling*) do `h4` clicado, e ocorre imediatamente depois do mesmo. Para selecioná-lo então, pode-se usar [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), e então proceder para a busca nos seus descendentes:

```
$("h4").click(function() {
    $(this).next().find("li").toggle();
});
```

Caso ele esteja somente próximo, mas não imediatamente próximo, outra opção seria usar `nextAll` e buscar o primeiro `ul` encontrado:

```
$("h4").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll("ul:eq(0)").find("li").toggle();
});
```

Comment: O next é boa opção aqui. `+1`

Answer (score 3):

Teste assim:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('h4').each(function(index){
          $(this).click(function(){
              $(this).parent().find('ul').eq(index).find('li').toggle();
           });
    });
});
</script>
```

### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/rczL9h0n/

A dificuldade aqui é que todos os `<h4>` tem o mesmo pai, assim têm de guardar o index de cada e chamar o [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) para selecionar o elemento `ul` certo.

Também pode usar o [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) e fazer o mesmo com uma classe CSS.

Comment: Estou no celular agora e não consigo testar, mas voce tentou com .closest('ul') ?

Comment: @Jader `closest` busca nos ancestrais do elemento, e não nos irmãos.

Comment: @mgibsonbr de fato, a função real não condiz com a tradução literal... falha minha!